# Reading cURL request from receiving side to find out which file is requesting

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way to read a curl request from receiving side to find out which files they are requesting from?

Below is the curl request from requesting side...

```
$ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed_url);

        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

        foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
            echo "<p><b> $entry->title </b></p>";
            echo "<p> $entry->description </p>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the filename as a GET or POST parameter in your curl call.
in PHP it is as simple as using `__FILE__`  variable as one of the POST/GET parameters.

Comment: I cannot change any details the requesting side. Can we identify from receiving side if it's just curl read?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your server log files? The log files should contain a list of all requests, including those made by curl.